# Bluetooth headphones controls problem after Android 7.1.1 Nougat update (Galaxy J5 2016)

Tags: bluetooth, 7.0-nougat

I just installed an Android 7.1.1 Nougat update on a Galaxy J5 (2016) phone in our family. (It's running Samsung Experience 8.5, if that's relevant.) There's an annoying problem with Bluetooth stereo headphones that previously worked flawlessly with many phones, including this one. The problem is that Play/Pause button stops the playback (as it should), but another press doesn't resume it. I've tried rebooting the device, unpairing, switching bluetooth on and off, and nothing helps. Could someone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this depends on:
1. How good the music app you are using is programmed.
2. Which [`KeyEvents`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) your Bluetooth headset sends and how your app handles them.
I guess your headset uses same button for play/pause so there might not be proper handling of `KeyEvents` on the app side.
The solution is to try different app for music playback, check if YouTube app is working OK with your headset.
I will suggest you to use Google Play Music, as it works great with my Bluetooth headset with single play/pause button, running on Moto G4 Play (Android version 7.1.1).

Comment: Many thanks for you good advice. We do use a headset with one button for play/pause. 
I tried playback on YouTube app and it works, so the problem must be what you mentioned, how each app handles KeyEvents. I'm now wondering is how come the same podcasts app we use worked nicely on the previous Android. 
Anyway, it seems I have to find a new app for podcasts. The one used now is a Podcast player Acast. It was chosen as it's free with a good-looking UI and 15 sec jump buttons.